# MVC 4 adding a custom class to a html after unsuccessful validation

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4, while analyzing the 'Register' View of, default internet MVC web application, provided in Visual studio i found that for the username input element, it was initally like this

```
<input id="UserName" type="text" value="" name="UserName"></input>
```

but after an unsuccessful validation it changed to

```
<input id="UserName" class="input-validation-error" type="text" value="" name="UserName"></input>
```

I disabled the ClientValidation and UnobtrusiveJavascript in the Web.config file.

I want to to know

1. how this class attribute is added to the input element. Is there a javascript involved for this?
2. How can i change the class name in the class attribute rendered in the input element.

Comment: just remove jquery unobtrusive js file from your view..

Comment: i am asking something else, i want to know how to change the name of class.

Comment: Just try below code...it will work...

Comment: then without using jquery you cant do it because these class is autogenerated in mvc...

Comment: this will help you....http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/bcWO151212-How-to-Enable-and-Disable-Client-Side-Validation-in-MVC.html

Answer (score 0):

If You want to change class name then you can do this with jquery as :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[class='input-validation-error']").removeClass("input-validation-error").addClass("errorclass") 
 });
```

in place of `"errorclass"` you can have any class name of your choice

Comment: thanks Exception,

I know how to do it with jQuery, i want to know how to it without jquery,

I intentionally disabled clientvalidation and unobstrusive javascript.